# Why can't I give a comment for my question and choose a best answer?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

As title!I want to give a comment for my question by typing the "post a comment", but it doesn't work.
Also,I want to choose a best answer for my question by clicking the tick, but it takes no effort.

What should I do?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/44708/why-can%27t-i-give-a-comment-for-my-question-and-choose-a-best-answer?/) by [seanbyxm](https://answers.ros.org/users/3252/seanbyxm/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2012-09-27

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You should take into account that usually it takes a while (5 to 10 seconds) for your browser to show the effect of "clicking" on "post a comment" or "vote" or "choose a best answer".

Just be patient :)

---

Originally posted by [Martin Peris](https://answers.ros.org/users/1108/martin-peris/) with karma: 5625 on 2012-09-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2